# What is the best way to stop tiny ants from entering my home?

Tags: pest-control, ants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent insects from entering my house? How can I find their entry point?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/how-can-i-prevent-insects-from-entering-my-house-how-can-i-find-their-entry-poin)

I've got tiny ants coming in from the window above the sink in the kitchen.  We are taking care to make sure the area is more clean since the ants started coming in.  I've tried a few products, and I seem to have the best luck with the Terro liquid poison (I don't remember the exact name at the moment).  When they come in, they don't go too far beyond the poison.  However, they don't seem to be going away.  It seems that I have to keep that stuff out there constantly since they started coming this summer.  I feel like I'm just giving them a nice meal.  I'm interested in product recommendations, or any other ideas.  I'm not afraid to poison the heck out of those suckers!

Comment: Tiny [Mind Control Devices](http://www.google.com/patents?id=ZpszAAAAEBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=3,951,134&hl=en&ei=H794TunHI4ba0QGQhpH0Cw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAA)!

Comment: Possible duplicates: [How can I prevent insects from entering my house?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/how-can-i-prevent-insects-from-entering-my-house-how-can-i-find-their-entry-poin) and [How can I get rid of ants in an environmentally friendly way?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/660/how-can-i-get-rid-of-ants-in-an-environmently-friendly-way)

Comment: @Tester101: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicrocoelium_dendriticum

Comment: @Aarthi - Maybe the responses will end up as duplicates, but: "prevent insects" - too general, and "environmentally friendly" - I would like to permanently get rid of the ants, and I'm thinking boiling water won't do the trick.

Comment: @BMitch: Guess I better stop eating ants!

Comment: Tiny ants?  They might be odorous ants (when you crush 'em, they smell vaguely like coconut), which are particularly annoying as most common ant baits don't work on 'em.

Comment: Coconut flavored ants, Mmmmmmmmm.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed.  Asking "how do I keep ants from entering my home" is not the same as asking "how do I keep insects like grasshoppers from entering my home".  It's also not the same as "how do I get rid of ants" (see other linked question) because that guy was talking about pouring hot water into their mound, so this was most likely outside.

Answer (score 5):

You have to stop them at the source. Use baits that ants will gather and take back to their nest, or follow the trail back to the nest and Raid the entire trail + nest.

I've also been known to put a pesticide in my lawn and flower beds once or twice a year to keep them from getting near the house. I try to make a 10' perimeter around the home.

Comment: Also keep in mind that ants use pheromones to mark trails, so you'll want to clean around entry points with detergent to get rid of the trails.