# How do I prevent small tiny insects (bugs / ants) that are crawling on the walls?

Tags: pest-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to stop tiny ants from entering my home?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9037/what-is-the-best-way-to-stop-tiny-ants-from-entering-my-home)
>   [How can I prevent insects from entering my house? How can I find their entry point?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8701/how-can-i-prevent-insects-from-entering-my-house-how-can-i-find-their-entry-poin)

Do I just spray some insect repellant on the wall? Do I just apply a new coat of anti-insect paint over it? Do I use wash the wall with vinegar or lemon juice?