# Should I add any additives when mixing Bifen IT

Tags: pest-control

Following the suggestion [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/224737/104944), I did a little searching and found two options for bug spray: an [off the shelf product](https://www.ortho.com/en-us/products/bugs/ortho-home-defense-insect-killer-indoor-perimeter2-refill) or [DIY](https://store.doyourownpestcontrol.com/bifen-it). In terms of per ounce active ingredients, the off the shelf solution is about ~10 times more expensive. I'm wondering if I go the DIY route, are there any additives I should add to increase the retention/longevity of the active ingredients in the perimeter barrier, like surfactants and ammonium sulfate for glyphosate?

Comment: How long are you targeting between applications?  When I used Bifen as a barrier, I had excellent results with a 4 month schedule in a wet and sunny environment.  For longer than that, you could try fipronil as a barrier.

Comment: Certainly the longer the better (hence the question) :) But 4 month sounds long enough! Was that just Bifen without any adjuvants?

Comment: Yes, in fact that identical product if I recall correctly.  It may depend on the pests in question, which were cockroaches in my situation.  I also recall that I used one of the richer mixture ratios as specified on the label, which may have contributed to the longevity.  This did make the dried product have a faintly milky residue, but this was a non-issue for an outdoor perimeter spray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With credits to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pestcontrol/comments/nk2q6p/are_there_recommended_additives_for_mixing_bifen/), there are a few adjuvants to mix with Bifen:

- [Insect growth regulators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect_growth_regulator): Pyriproxyfen (Nyguard), Methoprene (Precor).
- Pesticide synergist: [piperonyl butoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piperonyl_butoxide) (Exponent).
- [Wettable powders](https://www.solutionsstores.com/wettable-powders) formulations are often longer lasting.